# Simple Firebase Database Search Query

Tags: android, firebase, search, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have run into a problem with searching the firebase database. I have seen the other answers on the Stack overflow but with no luck.
my database reference looks like this:

`database.child("users").child(uid!!)`

And when I am searching the users by username, I do not know how to get inside this user id(uid).
Is there anybody who can help me?

The answers on stack overflow, I assumed, like this:

```
 mContentRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("users").orderByChild("title")
.startAt(searchText)
.endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff");
```

[here is the look of the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvoAS.png)

[Data I want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMK3U.jpg)

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot and indicate the exact data that you want to get.

Comment: I have added a photo to the question

Comment: So you want to get the data of a single user or of multiple users? Highlight on the screenshot the exact data that you want to get.

Comment: I want to get multiple data from that table with the Firebase Recycler Adapter

Comment: This is really a bit too broad to reasonably be able to answer on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why? I just want to get simple search for users... to let someone search for the users

Answer (score 0):

I read above that you want to use a firebase recycler adapter. For a query you can use a reference in its place too. Your above query was pointing to just a single user object rather than the whole list needed for firebase recycler adapter.

```
//To get the whole list of users
val queryReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("users")

//if you want to go to a specific user then use the following
val queryReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("users").orderByChild("userId").equalTo(uid!!)


//then populate the rested of your recyclerview
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter fireAdapter = FirebaseRecyclerAdapter(UserObject.class, R.id.recyclerItemLayout, viewHolderClass.Class, queryReference) {

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        UserObject currentUser = getItem(position);
        //populate recycler accordingly
    }
};

recyclerView.adapter = fireAdapter
```

Comment: I have done this, but how to get data with search query

Comment: @M.Simel I read your above comment that you are using a firebase recyclerview. Check if this answer helps you